# Inductance and Coil Diameter for High Frequency Transformer?

Tags: voltage-measurement, high-frequency

I am working on a project using Raspberry Pi and several components to operate high voltage equipment and read analog input from sensors for one of my clients.

I'm more a high level web developer but I have worked on these kind of projects in the past. **So my situation right now is**: I need to measure phase voltage (I'll be reading 100v~250v) and I contacted a company that makes this high frequency transformer that I need to achieve that. But they are asking for very specific data such as:

- Inductance
- Coil Diameter
- Winding Number

And they won't recommend this data to me (maybe to protect themselves). Can you guys recommend which specification to give to each one of these requirements?

Comment: Why is it called a high frequency transformer? Are there circuits already which can be used to detect high voltage or some data on high voltage for reference?

Comment: How are you planning to use this "high frequency transformer"?

Comment: Transformers have many properties. You need to define them

Comment: Thanks guys, this is the product I need: https://feleng.en.alibaba.com/product/60584814055-803280018/220v_12v_24v_transformer_220v_12v_micro_transformer_220v_12v_power_transformer.html?spm=a2700.7803228.1998738836.188.jekN7E and I don't know how to define those properties, thats why I'm asking hehe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may be able to use a transformer but also consider this as an option: -

[image]

It's an ADC isolated from ground (UL recognition: 2500 V rms for 1 minute per UL 1577) by the ADuM5401. The ADC is both powered by the ADuM5401 and talks to ground referenced equipment via SPI through that device's isolated ports.

So, using a precision voltage divider you can get better accuracy compared to a transformer. Anyway, it's food for thought should you want a back-up plan to the transformer idea.